# How does stream analytics query windowing work and how do I avoid double rows?

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I have a query in stream analytics to count the requests per hour. Therefore I have a group by cause and I got the message "a window is expected". So I added a tumblingwindow, but I do not understand how it is working.

```
group by
    datetimefromparts(year(r.starttime), month(r.starttime), day(r.starttime), datepart(hh, r.starttime),0,0,0),
    r.tags,
    r.IsMobile,
    tumblingwindow(hh, 1)
```

When I choose `hh` I got these 11 results:

```
requestdate                 tags    ismobilecount   summary
2016-10-03T21:00:00.000Z    A       0       6       2016-10-03T21:00:00.000ZA06
2016-10-03T21:00:00.000Z    B       0       1       2016-10-03T21:00:00.000ZB01
2016-10-03T22:00:00.000Z    A       0       20      2016-10-03T22:00:00.000ZA020
2016-10-03T21:00:00.000Z    B       0       1       2016-10-03T21:00:00.000ZB01
2016-10-03T22:00:00.000Z    B       0       14      2016-10-03T22:00:00.000ZB014
2016-10-03T21:00:00.000Z    A       1       2       2016-10-03T21:00:00.000ZA12
2016-10-03T21:00:00.000Z    B       1       1       2016-10-03T21:00:00.000ZB11
2016-10-03T21:00:00.000Z    B       1       1       2016-10-03T21:00:00.000ZB11
2016-10-03T21:00:00.000Z    A       1       1       2016-10-03T21:00:00.000ZA11
2016-10-03T22:00:00.000Z    A       1       15      2016-10-03T22:00:00.000ZA115
2016-10-03T22:00:00.000Z    B       1       22      2016-10-03T22:00:00.000ZB122
```

But when I choose `dd` (`tumblingwindow(hh, 1)`) I got these results:

```
requestdate                  tags ismobile  count   summary
2016-10-16T21:00:00.0000000Z    B       1       45      2016-10-16T21:00:00.0000000ZB145 
2016-10-16T22:00:00.0000000Z    A       0       51      2016-10-16T22:00:00.0000000ZA051 
2016-10-16T22:00:00.0000000Z    A       1       49      2016-10-16T22:00:00.0000000ZA149 
2016-10-16T22:00:00.0000000Z    B       0       41      2016-10-16T22:00:00.0000000ZB041 
2016-10-16T22:00:00.0000000Z    B       1       39      2016-10-16T22:00:00.0000000ZB139 
2016-10-16T23:00:00.0000000Z    A       0       3       2016-10-16T23:00:00.0000000ZA03  
2016-10-16T23:00:00.0000000Z    A       0       39      2016-10-16T23:00:00.0000000ZA039 
2016-10-16T23:00:00.0000000Z    A       1       2       2016-10-16T23:00:00.0000000ZA12  
2016-10-16T23:00:00.0000000Z    A       1       38      2016-10-16T23:00:00.0000000ZA138 
2016-10-16T23:00:00.0000000Z    B       0       1       2016-10-16T23:00:00.0000000ZB01  
2016-10-16T23:00:00.0000000Z    B       0       46      2016-10-16T23:00:00.0000000ZB046 
2016-10-16T23:00:00.0000000Z    B       1       29      2016-10-16T23:00:00.0000000ZB129 
2016-10-16T23:00:00.0000000Z    B       1       4       2016-10-16T23:00:00.0000000ZB14  
2016-10-17T00:00:00.0000000Z    A       0       42      2016-10-17T00:00:00.0000000ZA042 
2016-10-17T00:00:00.0000000Z    A       1       36      2016-10-17T00:00:00.0000000ZA136 
2016-10-17T00:00:00.0000000Z    B       0       39      2016-10-17T00:00:00.0000000ZB039 
2016-10-17T00:00:00.0000000Z    B       1       45      2016-10-17T00:00:00.0000000ZB145 
2016-10-17T01:00:00.0000000Z    A       0       41      2016-10-17T01:00:00.0000000ZA041
```

When I run my job for some days, I got 8 rows for 23:00:00h every day.

But I am expecting only 4 rows for every hour. How can I solve that? Can someone explain me how this is working and how to solve this problem?

Comment: In the second table you posted with 8 rows, every row seems unique. Groupby includes a datecolumn, tags and ismobile. And with those three columns, all rows seem unique. For example tag A has two rows for 2016-10-03T21:00:00.000Z, with ismobile = 0 and with ismobile = 1. Can you list down the two rows that you consider duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's due to your Tags always having A and B. This looks like it is expected behavior, since every hour you have an A and B. You will get the same thing with IsMobile when there are more than one distinct value in the hourly group.

So, based on Tags and IsMobile both having two possible choices every hour, you could have up to four rows per hour if there were the following events in that hour:

```
Tag: A, IsMobile: 0
Tag: A, IsMobile: 1
Tag: B, IsMobile: 0
Tag: B, IsMobile: 1
```

Comment: Yes, I am expecting 4 rows for each hour, but I receive 8 rows.

Comment: Kim, can you provide a sample message from your input stream?     SELECT * FROM [INPUT]

Comment: Oops, accidentally submitted that earlier. Can you provide a sample message from your input stream?

Comment: Wow, sorry, getting used to adding comments on here! Also, can you share the full stream query? I'm expecting to see a SELECT columns FROM [INPUT] GROUP BY columns